# Cant set a remote with PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am trying to get PyCharm set up to where I can mess around with it at home and at work off my laptop. I have BitBucket plugin installed on both. I try to push my main folder but I get an error "Can't push, because no remotes are defined".

Im going crazy over here. Been at it for well over 2 hours trying to find some way to make it work. If anyone knows the solution to this, that would be wonderful!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a remote. Right now, PyCharm does not know where to push your folder.
There are a few ways to do this.

The easiest one is to download the command plugin for pycharm, and add a remote by:

```
git remote add origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

After pointing git to a remote, push and pull should work correctly.

Comment: what plugin is that? I figured that would be how I would do it but was unable to find a plugin for command line

Comment: I can't find it as well, but I think you can try it from the command line, just make sure you have git in your path and navigate to your project folder

Comment: What exactly do you mean by having git in your path? I'm okay with command line buy not the best

Comment: That your terminal knows where to look for the git program.

Comment: You could also add the remote via terminal.

Answer (score 0):

when you push , you can add define remote in pycharm, on 'Push Commits'. and copy URL on it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VffK7.png)

[enter link description here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/managing-remotes.html)